# Hashmap is empty when ActionListener is called

Tags: java, hashmap, actionlistener

I have some code that looks like the following:

```
public class Application {

    public JTextField some_textfield;

    public HashMap<String, Integer> map;

    /*
     * public static main(String[] args)
     *  calls Application()
     */

    public Application() {
        initialize();
        initializeMap();
        System.out.println(map);
        //prints the map {"some_textfield" : 123}
    }

    private void initializeMap() {

        map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        map.put(some_textfield.getName(), 123);
        //...
    }

    private void initialize() {
        //...
        some_textfield = new JTextField();
        some_textfield.setName("some_textfield");
        some_textfield.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println(map);
                //map is empty
            }
        });
        //...
    }
}
```

When I type something in the text field and trigger the actionListener, it prints an empty map `{}` in the console.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried switching around `initializeMap()` and `initialize()` calls?

Comment: I forgot to add, that the map contains data, that is dependent on initialize() sorry. edited the question.

Comment: Post your real code. We can't find a real bug in fake code.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I had posted that as an answer, but it's just occurred to me that the S.o.p line is in an ActionListener, so the map should still be populated when it's clicked. Fullk33, if initialize() is where you load the data into the map, do you mind sharing your entire initialize()? I suspect that's where the problem lies

Comment: If you initialize the map when you declare it, `public HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();`, it will be available to be captured by the `ActionListener`.

Comment: initialize() just adds a bunch of JComponents to the JFrame

Comment: I have tried initializing the HashMap but it does not seem to change anything.

Comment: Ok, but you said in your comment that the map's data is dependent on initialize(). We need to see what you've done with map before this ActionListener is pressed, because the code you've given in the post works fine. The problem has to be somewhere else

Comment: The only thing that the map is dependent on, is the `setName()` of `some_textfield` because I call `getName()` in initializeMap(). I dont do anything else to the hashMap.

Comment: The code you gave us doesn't have the problem in your question. It works. We cannot fix your problem if we can't see it happening.

Comment: Good news: ***the code shown is basically correct.*** Though I suspect you simplified things for us (thanks), and there is at one double declaration of map or some_textfield, or an exception was thrown, swept under the carpet with a `catch`.

Comment: thanks, hm, I will take a look at that and see if I can find that  double declaration

Comment: Hm so all my catches print the stacktrace and I am not getting any of that when I run my code. I don't think there are any exceptions being thrown.

Comment: did you try the code you gave us? Does it produce the behavior you specified?

Comment: Its true. This code I gave you works, mine does not. I'll have to debug some more...

Comment: I have found my problem. I ran some code after `initializeMap()` which somehow cleared the map. My bad. Thank you guys anyway!